Blender 4.0 - Point lighting is dimmer than expected
I'm using Blender 4.0, and I'm trying to light my scene without world lighting. I turned the World Surface Strength to zero based on some tutorials I've seen. I've then added a point light, but the scene remains almost completely black with the default power of 10 W. I have to turn up the wattage to 5000+ to make things reasonably visible which seems a lot higher than what I've seen used in tutorials.


Here's the top view of my scene with the point light and a cube. The cube is the default cube size of 2m x 2m.

Am I missing something fundamental in how the strength of lighting should work?

To add to Lauloque's answer, your light is sitting something like 15m above ground : 7000W feels alright.

This is a normal phenomenon, considering you have a 10m radius lamp emitting only 10 Watts of energy.
To give you an idea, a common incandescent lightbulb for a small room is 40W. But that lightbulb is a few centimeters. So your light is 1000cm (10m) and only 10W, meaning you have 4 times less power to spread on a surface  thousand times bigger.

Add to this the fact that Eevee doesn't have global illumination (at least not until Blender 4.2), which means that light doesn't bounce around and therefore struggles to spread and illuminate as they do in Cycles.
So you could reduce the size and power of the light, put it closer, ... Or keep it big and powerfull and away. Both technically work and there isn't an absolute best thing.
At the end of the day, unless you are doing a scientific paper on the spread of light or you work in a project that demands realistic scale and accuracy to the cm, keeping realistic metrics isn't needed.
Whatever gives you a final render that you like in the least amount of time should be fine.
And since the result depends on properties that interact with each other, all you need to care about is understanding how they do so, and you will be able to make your jam as you please.

So is the best way to have point lights actually light the scene to just increase the power and possibly decrease the radius?

Another thing that threw me is that I attempted to use the Tri-Lighting add-on. It also produced a completely dark scene with default settings which was unexpected.

If you're looking for general non-directional lighting I'd use Area lights rather than Point lights.

You can do that, or leave it bigger and stronger. Both technically work and there isn't an absolute best thing. At the end of the day, unless you are doing a scientific paper on the spread of light or you work in a project that demands realistic scale and accuracy to the cm, it doesn't matter. Whatever gives you a final render that you like in the least amount of time should be fine. And since the result depends on properties that interact with each other, all you need to care about is understanding how they do so, and you will be able to make your jam as you please.

For the three-point lighting addon, Yes by default it's pretty dark. But also by default there is ambient lighting from the world ;) That's how it looks like with default world and lights (I just added a checkered plane below the cube to receive shadows): https://i.imgur.com/JgO0W94.png It's pretty neutral, it gives you a sane ground to work from.

The default light settings in Blender are arbitrary and very confusing and most people don't get just how dim light bulbs are. In any case, the numerical values are not that relevant, just their ratios are important for realism. One can use any numbers if needed. If it needs to be 10 000, that's fine, or one can increase exposure and have the lights at 0.001 it doesn't matter. See this https://blendermarket.com/products/extra-lights for more info and an add-on that seems to let you use somewhat realistic values in lumens, there is a free version.

Sorry for the down-vote, but I do see this as misleading. I mean the whole comparason of 40W incandescent light bulb to Blender's 10W radiance energy.

@MartynasŽiemys ignoring whether 40W is comparable to blender 10W, is the concept of point light having smaller surface area resulting in brighter light and larger surface area resulting in less light due to it being spread across more surface area accurate?

It's the same amount of light, but it's a tricky subject. It's not the same thing to have a weaker light closer as a stronger light further away, because the falloff is different. Strong light further away will have less fall off across the space you might have your subject in. Also the size is tricky - it's the same amount, but because of geometry, the bigger the light the less of it might hit your subject directly.

One more thing: there is no such thing as common incandescent light bulb. You almost cannot get them any more. In the times when they were common 40W bulb was really dim for a room. That's only around 450 lumens. I have 1060lm bulb illuminating the room I am sitting in and only 100lux is hitting my desk(200lx is technically required for public toilets where I live if I am not mistaken, not that I have ever seen anyone at all caring about that :D )
